# Некорретный вывод текста в релиз версии

Tags: c, winapi

В Code::Blocks пишу программу, часть кода работает странно: если компилирую дебаг версию, то при запуске проги строка текста выводится правильно, но в версии релиз вместо текста кракозябры (текст будто сплющен), хотя код тот же. Что не так? Что делать?

```
  hFont = CreateFontIndirect ( & LogFont );
  SelectObject ( HdcRis,  hFont );
  SetTextColor (  HdcRis,  RGB ( 0, 0, 0 )  );
  SetBkColor ( HdcRis,  RGB ( CvetFonaR, CvetFonaG, CvetFonaB )  );

  TextOut (  HdcRis,  WirinaRamki + 3,  WirinaRamki + 1,  Fl. Imx,  _tcslen ( Fl. Imx )  );

  DeleteObject(hFont);
```

Comment: Тут все зависит от содержимого `LogFont` и `Fl.Imx`. Смотрите, как Вы заполняете эти сущности.

Comment: @mega, огромное спасибо! Я поправил `LogFont` и всё заработало как надо.